# How to reduce size of git repo on local machines via "gt lfs prune"?

Tags: git, binary, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I'm adding these parameters to config file, but I'm not sure about formatting.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = XXX
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[lfs "XXX"]
    access = basic
    pruneoffsetdays = 0
    fetchrecentrefsdays = 0
    fetchrecentremoterefs = 0
    fetchrecentcommitsdays = 0
```

These settings should erase all unnecessary versions stored in .git folder on local machines. I'm doing it right?

At this point, my local folder is about double size of the actual repo. I don't think I can shrink it more, but at least I wanna be sure to have done everything in a proper way.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I changed your [lfs] tag to [git-lfs]. The first is for Linux from Scratch, not Git Large File Storage. Might help you get better answers. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, in the meatime I've discovered that Repo will be anyway at least two time the size of himself.